# how to load page from hyperlink in JSF-2.2

Tags: jsf-2

I have hyperlinks as mentioned below in my page

```
a href="index.xtml?module=trans&action=test">Test  /a>   (using anchor tag)

a href="index.xtml?module=trans&action=test1">Test 1 /a> (using anchor tag)

a href="index.xtml?module=trans&action=test2">Test 2 /a> (using anchor tag)
```

Where `module = name` of folder where test.xhtml...test2.xhtml files are stored and action = name of the page i.e. test.xhtml...test2.xhtml.

On click of Test..Test2  link browser will load index.xhtml. In index.xhtml, I want to check if value of module and action is not null then it should load respective page (i.e. trans/test.xhtml onclick of Test link, trans/test1.xhtml onclick of Test 1 link...etc).

Can any one help me to achieve this task using JSF 2.2?